# Python, How to return result in same type as the input

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, types

I want to create a function that flattens every possible genest combination of iterables and returns the result in the same type as the input.

So far I created the following function. But it's not working like I want it to work. For example:

> flatten_iterable(([1, 2, 3], {4, 5, 6}, (7, 8, 9)))

Gives the following result:

> (1, 2, 3, {4, 5, 6}, 7, 8, 9)

As you can see, the set is still there

And when the input is a set, I get the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
def flatten_iterable(something):
    new_list = []
    x = type(something)
    if isinstance(something, (list, tuple)):
        for a in something:
            new_list.extend(flatten_list(a))
    else:
        new_list.append(a_list)
    new_list2 = x(new_list)
    return new_list2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is that when the input is a set, you append a set to `new_list` and then you try to convert that list to a set again, but this doesn't work since it contains a set which is unhashable. You should be returning the set right away (i.e. use `else: return something`).

Comment: How deep should the flattening go?

Comment: Actually, what you're asking for (I mean the " returns the result in the same type as the input" part) is just plain impossible given Python's definition of "iterable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def flatten_iterable(input_):
    for item in input_:
        if hasattr(item,'__iter__') and not isinstance(item, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten_iterable(item)
        else:
            yield item
```

Comment: Checking for `Iterable` might overflatten the input, because strings, files and many other objects are iterable.

Comment: Thats Right, I think I should add `bytes` to the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

`isinstance(something, (list, tuple))` is clearly false for sets, that's why you are adding the whole set to the result. A better way is to check `hasattr(something, '__iter__')` (with the caveat it would "flatten" strings as well). I like @mehrdad-pedramfar's answer much better though